# Nonetype object isn't iterable

Tags: python, object, nonetype, iterable, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm new to Python so I decided to replicate this one

youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kU3_b78JpA&ab_channel=NikunjPanchal

But there is an error in coding section

```
from machine import UART, Pin
bt = UART(0,9600)

L1 = Pin(2,Pin.OUT)
L2 = Pin(3,Pin.OUT)

while True:

    br = bt.readline()

    if "ON1" in br:
        L1.value(0)
    elif "OFF1" in br:
        L1.value(1)

    elif "ON2" in br:
        L2.value(0)
    elif "OFF2" in br:
        L2.value(1)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object isn't iterable
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Always tag your questions with the programming language. That will ensure they are seen by the most people.

Comment: Have you checked the value in `br`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion also I am pretty new to this so I am completely lost right now but I will try.

Comment: By "progamming language" I meant `python'... :)

Comment: Oh lol sorry hahahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop where you populate the `br` variable. If you [read the machine.UART.readline() documentation](https://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.8.6/wipy/library/machine.UART.html#machine.UART.read) you'll see that `None` is returned in the event of a timeout. You need to confirm that there is a value stored in the variable before you check the content.

```
from machine import UART, Pin

bt = UART(0,9600)

L1 = Pin(2,Pin.OUT)
L2 = Pin(3,Pin.OUT)

while True:

    br = bt.readline()

    # Check for timeout
    if br is not None:

        if "ON1" in br:
            L1.value(0)
        elif "OFF1" in br:
            L1.value(1)

        elif "ON2" in br:
            L2.value(0)
        elif "OFF2" in br:
            L2.value(1)
```